# boundary condition of perpendicular component of electric field of a thin sheet

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, classical-electrodynamics, boundary-conditions

This question is in reference to *Introduction to Electrodynamics* by *David Griffith*

[image]

By Gauss's law:

$\oint_{S} \vec{E}.d\vec{a}=\frac{Q_{enclosed}}{\epsilon_{0} }$

where

$Q_{enclosed}$ is the charge enclosed by a Gaussian surface.

If we imagine a Gaussian pillbox of area A with a finite depth on the "top" face of the sheet, we take the sum electric field of an eclosed charge through the surface A and the electric field of the same enclosed charge through the sides of finite depth.

But, by the dot product, only the component of the electric field perpendicular to the surface $d\vec{a}$ of the Gaussian pillbox exists.

So, $\vec{E} = \frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_{0} }\hat{n}$

where $\sigma$ is the surface charge density.

Griffith's explanation that $E^{\perp }_{above}-E^{\perp}_{below}=\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_{0} }$ does not enable me to fully understand how this expression is arrive at.

Perhaps, someone may be able to assist me with the schematic set up so that I may have a better insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $\oint_{S} \vec{E}.d\vec{l}=\frac{Q_{enclosed}}{\epsilon_{0} }$.

It is not a line integral on the left hand side but a surface integral which states that the net electric flux out of an enclosed surface is equal to the net charge enclosed by the surface divided by the permittivity.

So in this case

$$E^{\perp }_{above}A-E^{\perp}_{below}A=\frac{\sigma A}{\epsilon_{0} }$$

which leads to Griffith’s result.

The expression $\vec{E} = \frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_{0} }\hat{n}$ is true for the electric field at the surface of a conductor where $E^{\perp}_{below}$ inside the conductor is zero.

Comment: The mistake has been edited.

Comment: I'm curious as to how a schematic would look like.
Your last sentence seems to imply that there are 'charges' within the conductor. If the conducting sheet is infinitesimally thin, could we not just think of charges on the surface of the sheet?

Comment: @Physkid The charges would be on the surface and electric field found is infinitesimally above the surface.